# Can I call a method from another class in an ASPX page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some logic in a class called CustomValidation that I'm currently calling in my C# code:

```
protected void EmailValidator(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    string strInput = args.Value.Trim();
    CustomValidation v = new CustomValidation();
    args.IsValid = v.ValidateEmail(strInput);
}
```

I would rather call such methods from my ASPX page to simplify things, like this:

```
<asp:CustomValidator OnClick="ValidateEmail" />
```

However, since ValidateEmail is not in the same class as the page:

```
'ASP.editusers_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'ValidateEmail' and no extension method 'ValidateEmail' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.editusers_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Is there a way to call methods from the CustomValidation class in my ASPX code?  I've tried the following to no avail:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="ThisProject.CustomValidation" %>

OnClick="<%= CustomValidation.ValidateEmail()" %>
```

Here is my usage in context:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserEmail") %>' MaxLength="30" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="vldEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidateEmptyText="true" OnServerValidate='<%# RetailCrime.CustomValidation.ValidateEmail((string)(txtEmail.Text)) %>' ErrorMessage='<br /><label class="invisible noplaceholder">&nbsp;</label>Please enter a valid email.' Display="Dynamic" CssClass="validatormessage" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by making a `static` `delegate`.

```
public class CustomValidator
{
    public static void EmailValidator(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        string strInput = args.Value.Trim();
        CustomValidation v = new CustomValidation();
        args.IsValid = v.ValidateEmail(strInput);
    }
}

<asp:CustomValidator OnClick="CustomValidator.EmailValidator" />
```

Comment: If I change my method to static, I get `Member 'RetailCrime.CustomValidation.ValidateEmail(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`.

Comment: try to qualify it with `CustomValidation`, i.e. `CustomValidation.ValidateEmail`

Comment: I think that is because you call it on another place with the instance. Try to copy the method and call it ValidateEmailStatic and try again.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the problem is.  Trying again :)

Comment: Hi. My method is now static in my class and I'm still getting the "does not contain a definition" error.  If I try to call it like `<%= CustomValidation.ValidateEmail(someEmailField.Text) %>`, I'm told "identifier expected".

Comment: Progress!  I guess I'm finding it this way: `OnServerValidate='<%# RetailCrime.CustomValidation.ValidateEmail((string)(txtEmail.Text)) %>`.  Now I'm told that txtEmail doesn't exist in the current context.  A new problem?

Comment: @PatrickHofman - His second example will call `CustomValidation.ValidateEmail()` during page rendering, not when the click happens. This is certainly not what he is after.

Comment: To be clear, if I use `<%= CustomValidation.ValidateEmail("sometext") %>`, the validation works just as expected.  The application uses my ValidateEmail code to test out the text "sometext".  The only problem now is being able to reference the `txtEmail.Text` instead of "sometext".

Comment: OnServerValidate expects a delegate. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.onservervalidate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Help the uneducated :)  I'm not sure how to to integrate that fact into my understanding of the problem and solution.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, I'll still need to have a function in my codebehind to call the function in the class file for the control.  There's no way to have the ASPX page get the function from the class file directly and pass the value of the textbox.

Comment: That is exactly what the above code does. You place this in a single class and reuse it everywhere.

Comment: Actually, I think my problem has to do with the fact that my textbox is in the edititemtemplate of a gridview.  It just doesn't exist yet when I load the page.  If I replace txtEmail.Text with litNow.Text (a literal from somewhere else on the page that exists as soon as the page loads), I get no errors.

Comment: Can't you add the validator inside?

Comment: It is.  It's right beside the textbox in the markup.  But it only works if I reference  a textbox that's not in the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a validator method that you want to access from at least 2 or more pages. Remember the single responsibility principle.

While the static approach works, you can statically access the validation method that is defined in the edit users page class. But this email validation is really quite generic and could be used for more than just editing users. So if you look at your original error "... does not contain a definition for 'ValidateEmail' and no extension method ...", you could create an extension method.

To extend a class you'll need a common interface to apply to any class you want to be extended. For example:

```
public interface IMyValidations { }
```

and create the extension class

```
public static class MyValidations
{
    public static void ValidateEmail(this IMyValidations target, string input)
    {
        // magic happens here
    }
}
```

and create your concrete classes

```
public class MyFirstClass : IMyValidations
{
}

public class MySecondClass : IMyValidations
{
}
```

and wherever or however you create an instance of your concrete classes, you can access that method as an instance method

```
 MyFirstClass one = new MyFirstClass();
 one.ValidateEmail("foo@bar.com");
 MySecondClass two = new MySecondClass();
 two.ValidateEmail("hello@world.com");
```

This example is far from complete, it was thrown together to show how you can use an extension method to take that email validation out of that class. Obviously why would you pass in the email when you already have an instance of the target?

Any my final suggestion, email validation, and validation in general has been done time and time again. No need to re-invent the wheel. I'm sure there are a bazillion frameworks out there, but my favorite is [FluentValidations](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/). NuGet makes it ridiculously easy to set up.

Comment: This will require some re-working of my example, but I'll dig into it.  And why don't I just use an existing framework for validation?  I just enjoy writing code, so sometimes I like to re-invent the wheel a little so I can find new insights.

Comment: Yeah I understand about the reworking. Its not a quick solution. I like writing code too. Infact you can go all crazy with extensions and start writing your own fluent stuff by having the extension methods return instances of other things. You can go something like `myObj.ValidateThis().And.ValidateThat()`. Have fun!